# IP Restrictions with Nginx for GET arguments

Tags: nginx

I want to restrict access to urls in nginx like "/start?do=login" by IP. What to match is the argument "do=login". "start" itselfe is OK. How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!

at first I had this with "location /start" and it worked for "start" but there can also be ohter texts than "start". one for each page. This works for all pages:

```
error_page 418 = @do_login;
location / {
    recursive_error_pages on;
    if ($arg_do = login) {
        return 418;
    }
    index doku.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ @dokuwiki;
}

location @do_login {
    allow x.x.x.x/29;
    deny all;
    index doku.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ @dokuwiki;
}
```

Thanks to all for the hints!

Answer (score 1):

[This idea](http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil#What_to_do_instead) should work:

```
error_page 418 = @do_login;

location /start/ {
  if ($arg_do = login) {
    return 418;
  }
  # other directives for normal action
}

location @do_login {
  allow xx.xx.xx.xx;
  deny all;
  # other directives for normal action
}
```

Comment: compiles but with no effect. not allowed ip ranges still get the login page in stead of 403, even if I do closer what is written in the link. perhaps i should add that it is a dokuwiki site with rewrite enabled.

Comment: @mahescho provide full nginx config

Comment: when I use "location /start" in stead of "location /start/" I get a 404 on "/start"

Comment: Did you add `# other directives for normal action`?

Comment: not when I got 404. with my soulution below, yes. I'm completely new to nginx. learnd a lot in this thread, thanks again to all.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this for example

```
location /start/ {
  if ($args ~ do=login) {
    allow xx.xx.xx.xx;
    deny all;
  }
}
```

Comment: already tried that, but it is not that simple. this gets: "nginx: [emerg] "allow" directive is not allowed here"

Comment: `$args ~ do=login` is too broad. `$arg_do = login` is better.

Comment: yea I thought so but then I decided to just copy what the doc had, but thanks